# Which channels to have a raid 5 array on the Intel ICH10R controller?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata

What is the best option to have a raid 5 array with 3 disks in the six channel Intel ICH10R controller?
On channel 1, 3 and 5. Channel 1, 2 and 3  etc...

Or doesnt this matter on the performance?

Answer (score 1):

Does not matter, using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to enter the Intel option ROM RAID configuration utility to choose hard drives to be included in the RAID 5 array, any other ports/drives will operate independently of the RAID array and will not interfere with performance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand page 29 of [this ICH10R spec](http://www.intel.nl/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/io-controller-hub-10-family-specification-update.pdf) correctly then all ports are equal. Non is faster than an other.

Thus the answer is 'it does not matter'.

OCD persons might still like to use ports 0,1,2,3 etc and label their disks accordingly, though most RAID implementations do not care if the disk to port cables get mixed up at a later time.

Screenshot of page 29 from that manual, to make sure it does not go off-line.

[image]